# How to insert string into mysql using python correctly?

Tags: python, mysql, string

I'm quite new to python and mysql.
When I try to insert some records with fields of string, I failed to insert them into mysql because it always report error like: `ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax`.
I am quite confused.
Occasionlly, I find it works by add additional "" to the string field, like the following:

```
history_market_table_name = 'my_test'
f = ['field_a', 'field_b', 'field_c', 'field_d']
r = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
my_time = "'" + str(datetime.now()) + "'"
target_sql = "insert into %s (time, %s, %s, %s, %s) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"  % (
history_market_table_name, f[0], f[1], f[2], f[3], my_time, repr(r[0]), repr(r[1]), repr(r[2]), repr(r[3]))
```

Sorry the codes are quite tedious.
Moreover, there must be something wrong with my method -- it couldn't be so stupid to insert fields with string type!
Look at the `my_time` variable, how ridiculous.

Any one please explain how to correctly insert string into mysql with python.
I am quit new. 
So please give a correct answer and detailed explaination is highly appreciated.

Comment: You need quotes around the string values.

Comment: In fact, Python is so great that you can actually do that (need quotes however). I would just advise you to escape the characters to prevent injection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information. Now I learnt something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your format string to

```
"insert into %s (time, %s, %s, %s, %s) values(%s, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
```

I.e, single quotes around the otherwise-unquoted string values you're inserting -- and lose the `repr` calls after the `%`.  This will still fail if you're inserting a string value which **contains** a `'` character... there are better ways but they don't let you parameterize the table name and field names (which is a truly peculiar requirement...), only the **values**.

Added: as the OP requires "a direct expression for the 'target_sql' variable", here it is:

```
fmt_str = "insert into %s (time, %s, %s, %s, %s) values(%s, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
target_sql = fmt_str % (history_market_table_name, f[0], f[1], f[2], f[3], 
                        my_time, r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3])
```

I think it's more readable split up this way.  As for "some documents for such things" which the OP also requires, MySQL has such documents with every version (and the OP didn't mention which version he or she uses) and so does Python (ditto, ditto).

The "better way" (which however **don't** allow parameterizing table and field names) involve using "placeholders" in lieu of value in the SQL string, rather than string substitution.

Here,
    sql = "insert into my_test (time, field_a, field_b, field_c, field_d) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'

(with hard-coded, not parameterized, table and field names), and later, for a given `cursor` opened on the MySql DB,

```
cursor.execute(sql, (
    str(datetime.now()), r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3]))
```

with no worries about quoting nor about any potential for a "sql injection" attack.

Comment: Will you please give a direct expression for the 'target_sql' variable in my case? Thanks

Comment: Or please provide some documents for such things. It really confuses me a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by the 'better ways'? I could use it without parameterizing the table name and field names.

Comment: I tried you codes and they work quite well, except one thing: I use my_time = "'" + str(datetime.now()) + "'". Then I try to directly use my_time = datetime.now() but it reports "ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax;". Any suggestions?

Comment: @Deep_fox, for the string-interpolation approach you do need the single quotes around the `%s`.  So if you don't want to have `my_time` be a string complete with the quotes, use `'%s'` for it, as you do for `r[0]` &c, in the format string (then you don't need the `str` around it as interpolating with `%s` will do that intrinsically anyway).

Comment: I rewrite my code according to your suggestion about the better way using placeholders. Can the following codes be considered as 'hard-coded, not parameterized, table and field names' so as to prevent "sql injection" attack? Thanks so much.    sql = "insert into %s (time, %s, %s, %s, %s)" % (history_market_table_name, f[0], f[1], f[2], f[3])
sql += ' values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
cursor.execute(sql, (str(datetime.now()), r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3]))

Comment: @Deep_fox, it can be a usable compromise -- you still need care about the table & field names since you're inserting them via string formatting, but you're using the safe way for the values.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will pay more attention to the table & field names to prevent potential SQl injection.